# How is the day of the week unicorn?

Tags: prolog, zebra-puzzle

Task: The Unicorn is known to lie on Mondays, Tuesdays, and Wednesdays and tells the truth on all other days of the week. He can say: “Yesterday I lied. After tomorrow, I will lie for two days in a row. ” Determine the day of the conversation.

I sketched the code, but I don’t know how to say that the unicorn lied for two days in a row, correct the code, thanks in advance.

```
yesterday(mon, sun).
yesterday(tue, mon).
yesterday(wed, tue).
yesterday(thu, wed).
yesterday(fri, thu).
yesterday(sat, fri).
yesterday(sun, sat).

lies([mon, tue, wed]).

tomorrow(Day, Tomorrow) :-
    yesterday(Tomorrow, Day).

unicornLies1(Day) :- 
    lies(Days),
    member(Day, Days).

unicornLies2(Day) :- 
    tomorrow(Day, Tomorrow),
    unicornLies1(Day),
    unicornLies1(Tomorrow).

sol:- unicornLies1(Day), unicornLies2(Day), write(Day).
```

Comment: This **is** a simple instance of a [tag:zebra-puzzle], so no reason to remove that tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a simple logic that implements `next_day` and is used conversely to get the day before and after

```
day(X) :- member(X,[m,t,w,thu,f,sat,sun]).

lie(m).
lie(t).
lie(w).

truth(X) :- \+lie(X).

next(A, B, Ls) :- append(_, [A,B|_], Ls).

next_day(sun,m).
next_day(X,Y) :- next(X,Y,[m,t,w,thu,f,sat,sun]).

solve(X) :-
    day(X),
    (truth(X),next_day(Y,X),lie(Y),next_day(X,T),next_day(T,U),next_day(U,V),lie(U),lie(V));
    (lie(X),next_day(Y,X),truth(Y),next_day(X,T),next_day(T,U),next_day(U,V),(truth(U);truth(V))).
```

On running it gives a single result - Monday

```
?- solve(X).
X = m ;
```

Answer (score 0):

**Following day issue**

Write out a `follows` predicate instead of `yesterday` for clarity. You can pick out 'tomorrow' with `follows(Today, Tomorrow)`, the day after with `follows(Tomorrow, Overmorrow)` and the day three days from today with `follows(Overmorrow, ThreeDays)`. `Yesterday` can come from `follows(Yesterday, Today)`. Enforce your membership rules on `Yesterday`, `Overmorrow` and `ThreeDays`.

**Lying unicorn issue**

You have a semantic mistake. If the Unicorn is telling the truth (go through the possibilities!), there is no answer. Therefore you are really looking for a day where he lies *and* it is true that 'yesterday, I *didn't* lie. After tomorrow, I will *not lie* for two days in a row'. In other words, monday.

You will need to write a predicate that says that either `Today` is a not lying day and the predicate `says(Animal, Today)` is true, or `Today` is a lying day and `says(Animal, Today`) is false.

I'll leave the approach to you.

Comment: I changed the code, but did not understand about the following (Overmorrow, ThreeDays) (look at the code above).

Comment: @GOOse You need to bind two variables to a terms that represeent the two days after tomorrow, then ensure that these variables are bounded to days where the Unicorn lies.